# Requirements of Apache license

Tags: apache-2.0

I'm building a piece of commercial, closed-source software. I'm using an open-source piece of software called Neovim -- I want to include the Neovim binary in my software bundle that I distribute and leverage its functionality in my app.

Neovim uses the Apache 2.0 license. Is what I'm doing permitted, and if so, what are my obligations --  e.g. crediting Neovim, displaying a notice to the user, etc?

Comment: Which bits of the license did you find difficult to interpret? I know it's quite wordy, but Section 4 contains basically all you need.

Comment: Welcome to OS.SE!  That said, this question looks like a plea for someone to read a licence and lead you through it clause by clause, which isn't really what we do here.  If you can edit this question to show that you've read the licence, and to be more specific about exactly what remains confusing, that would be great; otherwise, I fear it may get closed as (eg) *lacking focus*.